Rebuilding the .deb for 6.5 linux kernel and Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS using kernel sources (git clone)
I have installed 6.5 linux kernel on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS using sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04.
I need to rebuild the kernel to enable CMA option but:

when getting the sources via apt source linux-image-unsigned-6.5.0-35-generic, the make deb-pkg complains that creating source package requires git repository (scripts/Makefile.package updated compared to 6.2 I was previously using)
when using git clone --depth 1 --branch Ubuntu-hwe-6.5-6.5.0-35.35_22.04.1 git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/jammy, kernel patches do not apply when I run make deb-pkg (here unsure why 6.5.13 is used for fetching the patches...):

[...]
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 6.5.13-g5554ac973c3d-1
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution jammy
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by rchevalier <rchevalier@Skaar>
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --compression=gzip --before-build .
dpkg-source: info: using options from jammy/debian/source/local-options: --diff-ignore --extend-diff-ignore=.*
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: building a source package without cleaning up as you asked; it might contain undesired files
 dpkg-source --compression=gzip -b .
dpkg-source: info: using options from jammy/debian/source/local-options: --diff-ignore --extend-diff-ignore=.*
dpkg-source: info: using source format '3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building linux-upstream using existing ./linux-upstream_6.5.13-g5554ac973c3d.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: using patch list from debian/patches/series
The next patch would delete the file debian/certs/canonical-livepatch-all.pem,```

and build fails.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel was just fine with 6.2 and previous versions but I am unable to get a working config for 6.5 kernel.

Could you help with me with 2. so I can recreate a .deb for 6.5 using git clone to get the source and properly applying the kernel patches?

Thanks!
RC


I was able to generate the .deb using rather 'make bindeb-pkg and updating the .config file to workaround signing issue (make[7]: *** No rule to make target 'debian/canonical-certs.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Stop.); that is setting CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="" and CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS=""...
Can someone point me to the right procedure to rebuild the kernel for linux-generic-hwe-22.04 ?
